# <section> tag background fixed image overlap on header

Tags: css, html

```css
section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-image: url("a.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center top;
    background-origin: content-box;
}
```

My css code but background starts at begining of website not under header? how can i solve problem

[summary of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9ohq.png)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] reproducing you problem.

Comment: I added an abstact of problem please look again

Comment: `If a web page problem requires HTML, some JavaScript and a stylesheet, include all three.` as per [mcve] definition. It's hard to help you otherwise..